# Tableau: Hyperlink auto open webpage based on Key ID

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, tableau-api

I was wondering if it's possible to create a hyperlink on Unique IDs I have on tableau to open a webpage that pre-enters the Unique ID on the web page's search bar and load it?

For example let's say i have a unique ID ABCD12345, when I click on it, I want it to load a web page on Internet Explorer(workplace still uses IE unfortunately...)
that will automatically enter the UNIQUE ID ABCD12345 into its search bar and open the web page based on that Unique ID.

*Note: unfortunately the webpage's search page URL does not contain any components of the unique ID, so embedding is out of question I'm afraid...*

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you want to send the info with POST method? If so, you may check here: https://community.tableau.com/thread/170755

Comment: Okay so my problem is if i click on the unique id "ABCDE12345" it should automatically search on the webpage. Let's say the webpage URL is www.example.com. In simple cases a simple search will display the url as for eg. "www.example.com/?search=ABCDE12345" however the webpage im using does not embed the key search words in its URL.
Does the HTTP post method solve this?

Comment: Basically yes! What you call "simple case" is HTTP GET method which you may see the passed parameters along with URL (just like you see in Google). Your website is apparently using is POST method and first you need to find out which and how the parameters are passed as soon as the "Search" button is being pressed in your web page.

Comment: Okay I'll read into HTTP POST method however one more question how do I find how the parameters are passed? Do I need to look into the source code of the page? If so what am i looking for?

Sorry with all these dumb questions... I'm trying to get familiar with this

Comment: This is another issue since there isn't any rule of thumb to get this info. Sometimes you may easily find this looking at the parameters of the search button, sometimes you should deep dive into the JavaScript codes. IMHO, create a new question providing the web site you mention in this question; I'm sure some HTML / JavaScript gurus will be in help for that.